# Сортировка записей в таблице mysql

Tags: массивы, php, mysql

На сайте есть слайдер-шоу. В админ панели есть пункт его настройки. В нем выводятся все картинки в порядке добавления в БД. Прикрутили кнопочки вверх-вниз, чтобы менять порядок слайдеров.
Допустим есть слайдеры в порядке **1,2,3,4**. Я выставляю новый порядок — **3,1,4,2**, нажимаю кнопку Update, и теперь мне необходимо все это дело зафиксировать в БД.
Таблица в БД имеет следующую структуру:

```
id,parent,key,name,type.
```

В данном случае задействованы только *id* и *name*.

```
"1,0,'',img1.jpg,section_slider"
```

и т.д. 
Сходу присвоить всем сразу новые айдишники не получится, надо как то через буфер. Возможно создать буферную запись, через *type* обозначить ее, для чего она. Подскажите как это все быстрее сделать. Количество слайдеров может быть теоретически любое, но на практике — больше 10 не было. Вариант "удалить записи, создать новые" — не подходит. Надо именно обновить *id* существующих.

Comment: А вариант добавить столбец, order_num например, в котором хранится именно порядок тоже не подходит?

Comment: Нет, большая таблица settings, где храниться очень много всякого добра) и для 2-х десятков слайдеров нет смысла так делать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все несколько проще чем казалось и DebilSort не помогло.
Как я решил проблему:
Через jQuery элемент sortable выставил новый порядок слайдеров. И по нажатии кнопки Save order получаю список id в нужном мне порядке. Записываю его в $data. Так же делаю выборку из бд и получаю старый порядок слайдеров, записываю его в sliders(имеет вид array(id,parent,key,name,type)). У меня используется mvc система, поэтому передаю это все дело в функцию которая работает с моделью. Код функции:

```
public function updateSliderOrder($data,$sliders)
{
    if (count($data)==count($sliders)){
        foreach ($sliders as $key=>$slider){
            $this->_updateData(array('id'=>'0'),array('id'=>$slider['id']),$this->_settings);
            $this->_updateData(array('id'=>$slider['id']),array('id'=>$data[$key]),$this->_settings);
            $this->_updateData(array('id'=>$data[$key]),array('id'=>'0'),$this->_settings);
        }
    }
}
```

PHP Doc к _upadateData:
/
     *** update data in table*
   


     * @param array $data array with pairs key=val of field and his value.
     * @param mixed $where sql where clause. can be array with key=val or string with conditions without 'WHERE'
     * @param strring $table [optional] table name on proccess with.
     * @return boolean on success return true otherwise false*
     /

Comment: Админы закрывайте, проблема не актуальна

Answer (score 0):

Не хранить в одной таблице "очень много всякого барахла" и создать нормальную таблицу, где будет храниться необходимая Вам информация. и имя и позиция и т.д.

Comment: Уже все сделано. Большой проект, соц. сеть. появилась необходимость сделать такую сортировку. ненадо мне советов типа добавить, убрать и т.д. я описал ситуацию и спросил вариант ее решения. Кроме того вы не знаете какая связь таблиц и вообще структуру проекта. там почти 50 таблиц и без этого

Comment: И вы думаете что 50 таблиц это так много?

Comment: Слушай, какая тебе вообще разница сколько у меня таблиц??? я поставил конкретную задачу и прошу подсказать ее решение